# Is this the right approach to time code speed?

Tags: python

I want to measure the speed of the primary function of my code, and I wrote the following code:

```
with open(filename + '.speed.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('result\ttime\ttext\n')
    for index, text in enumerate(textlines):
        #print(index)
        # 1. Start to time
        start = time.time()
        doc = bnlu.nlps(text, enable = enable)
        tags = defaultdict(set)
        if 'tag' in doc:
            for tag_id, tag_info_list in doc['wb_tag'].items():
                for tag_info in tag_info_list:
                    id = tag_id
                    name = tag_info[1]
                    weight = tag_info[2]
                    pattern_str = tag_info[4]
                    tag_str = '(' + id + ' ' + name + ' ' + pattern_str + ' ' + str(weight) + ')'
                    tags[id].add(tag_str)
        # 2. End to time
        end = time.time()
        time_1 = str(end-start)
      
        f.write(str(tags) + '\t' + time_1 + '\t' + text + '\n')

        # End to time 2
        end2 = time.time()
        time2 = end2-start
        print(time2)
```

The time consuming code is this part:

```
  doc = bnlu.nlps(text, enable = enable)
```

So my time_1 is to measure this part, and time_2 measures whether writing result of each line to a file takes much more time or just a little time compared with time_1.

Is this the right approach to measure code speed? In the resulting csv file, the 2nd column contains the time spent on each text line processed by the algorithm.

Also, the time_1 and time_2 are millseconds, right? In my output, these number are very small as below:

```
0.002065896987915039
0.002288341522216797
0.0019719600677490234
0.002459287643432617
0.0019350051879882812
0.002561807632446289
0.0022737979888916016
0.0026137828826904297
0.0020627975463867188
0.01592111587524414
0.001967191696166992
0.009980916976928711
0.007891178131103516
0.0022401809692382812
0.0035669803619384766
0.0030107498168945312
0.002779722213745117
0.0027618408203125
0.0019371509552001953
0.0025129318237304688
0.0023632049560546875
0.0022687911987304688
```

Does it mean only 0.00226 millisecond for the last? It looks suspicious since it is too fast. Is it second?

Comment: Assuming you're using at least Python 3.3, `time.perf_counter()` would be a better choice than `time.time()` as it's likely to have a higher resolution.  (It has no relationship with the actual clock time, but that's irrelevant if you are just subtracting two timestamps.)

Comment: An alternative to `time` is the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: This is python 3. Would time.perf_counter and timeit be much better than time.time(), or the comparison will be almost the same?

Comment: marlon: Yes, `time.perf` would be better.

Comment: Also, regardless of time not being the best tool for that, `start = time.time();time.sleep(1);end = time.time();print(end - start)` will print it in seconds, not milliseconds. If you want millisecond you have to multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeit https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html, for example:

```
def foo():
    return "hello"

timeit.timeit(foo,number=10)
```

Where `number` is number of repetition of time measure.

Comment: The pattern I generally use is `timing = min(timeit.repeat(repeat=REPETITIONS, number=NUM_EXECUTIONS)` where `REPETITIONS` and `NUM_EXECUTIONS` depend on exactly what's being timed.

Comment: In my case, I want to time the function, 'doc = bnlu.nlps(text, enable = enable)', then what format should I use? Also for each line to be processed from the file, the function is called in a loop. In such a case, I shouldn't use 'repeat' or 'number' parameter. Right? Because the loop has this effect already.

Comment: @marlon: `timeit` is for timing snippets of code, which can be sequences of statements and/or calls to a function. If you want to know how long individual lines of code are taking to execute, I would suggest that you use a [line-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/).